# OpenCV para python. Error: no module named cv2

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv, cv2

Estoy tratando de realizar un código para un proyecto usando la librería cv2, y todo el tiempo estoy teniendo el siguiente error:

> ImportError: No module named cv2

El código es el siguiente:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#read image into matrix.
m =  cv2.imread("python.png")

#get image properties.
w,h,bpp = np.shape(m)

#print image properties.
print "width: " + str(w)
print "height: " + str(h)
print "bpp: " + str(bpp)
```

Intenté instalar openCV  pero al parecer no se puede instalar correctamente, segui el [tutorial de esta página](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) y al querer instalar las dependencias me arrojo el siguiente error:

> E:Package 'libtbb-dev' has no installation candidate
>   E: unable to locate package libfaac-dev

Ignoré ese paquete y procedí al siguiente paso (descargar openCV 2.4.9).

Cuando traté de generar el Makefile usando `cmake` me arroja también los siguientes *warnings*:

> Could not find a package configuration file provided by  "Qt5Core" with any of the following names:
>          Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
>          qt5core-config.cmake
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
>           Call Stack (most recent call first)
>           CMakeLists.txt:466 (include)

Lo mismo pasa con los siguientes paquetes:

- Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
- qt5gui-config.cmake
- Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
- qt5widgets-config.cmake
- Qt5TestConfig.cmake
- qt5test-config.cmake
- Qt5ConcurrentConfig.cmake
- qt5concurrent-config.cmake

Al final me muestra este error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE QT_INCLUDE_DIR QT_LIBRARY_DIR QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR
  QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY QT_QTGUI_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY
  QT_QTTEST_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTTEST_LIBRARY QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1200 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:34 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:466 (include)
```

Ya he buscado en todas las carpetas del sistema y no he logrado encontrar los archivos anteriores. También leí que si algo salía mal, tengo que volver a pasos anteriores, corrigiendo los errores instalando los paquetes extras y volver a correr el `cmake` otra vez. Pero, ¿cómo puedo instalar esos paquetes extras?

Ya corrí los siguientes comandos y todas las librerías están instaladas y actualizadas a la versión más reciente.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get updgrade
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo instalar de la manera más simple posible y que sea correcta? En verdad lo apreciaría mucho, estoy trabajando en un proyecto de investigación y esa librería me está deteniendo.

PS. tampoco pude encontrar el archivo cv2.so.

Comment: Maybe your question will be better received in the official site of SO in english, this is SOes, the official site of SO in spanish. (sorry if my english is so primitive, i don´t write very well)

Comment: Por favor traduce la pregunta a español para que no sea cerrada en este sitio.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo  ya la traduci al espanol, alguna idea de mi problema? saludos, gracias ronquillo

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la carpeta C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages se deberia encontarse cv2.py sino instalalo manualmente.

Comment: como lo instalarias manualmente?

Comment: En la pregunta original se siguen instrucciones que corresponden a Ubuntu, no a Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**OpenCV** siempre la he utilizado desde los *packages* ya compilados, sólo la he utilizado desde código fuente en Windows, y más para estudiarla que por necesidad.

En **Linux** algunas bibliotecas están en otros respositorios y hace falta configurarlos manualmente. Tal vez la que te falta, `libfaac-dev`, es uno de esos casos. Y es raro que esa página no te lo incluya en la información. Para **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**, la información sobre el paquete de esa librería la tienes aquí: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libfaac-dev. Necesitarás buscar esa información para la *distro* en concreto que estás utilizando.

En **Ubuntu** (asumo que utilizas Ubuntu por el *link* que estás utilizando de las instrucciones) `libfaac-dev` está en el repositorio `multiverse`. Necesitarás comprobar si lo tienes configurado o no.

Comprueba el contenido de `/etc/apt/sources.list`, puede servirte `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Debería incluir estas líneas:

> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
> deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
> deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

Si no las incluye, prueba a incluirlas y luego ejecuta `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libfaac-dev`.